# Converting MATLAB sub2ind function to Python

Tags: arrays

I am converting this MATLAB code to Python. I am testing my class interpolation here to make sure the methods are working.
However, I am getting this  error message

> not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)***

The MATLAB `reshape` function in Python is not exactly the same.

I am also not sure about the nested function I created `sub2ind`.

Comment: To be clear your issue is wanting a sub2int function in python or you want to code one yourself?

Comment: Please post full traceback (error which is printed to console when you run this code).

Comment: Also please note that `__int__` probably should be `__init__`.

Comment: `sub2ind` is MATLAB's way of selecting items on a "diagonal" rather than a block.  `numpy` on the other hand handle this "diagonal" directly with `x[a,b]`, and requires a bit extra work to index the block.

Answer (score 1):

You souldn't translate `sub2ind` to Python. MATLAB and NumPy indexing work differently.
MATLAB's

```matlab
Im(sub2ind(size(Im),x,y))
```

with `x` and `y` vectors, indexes `Im` at (`x(1)`,`y(1)`), (`x(2)`,`y(2)`), etc. In Python you get the same indexing by writing:

```py
Im[x,y]
```